# How to Make True Zero Duration Instant Transitions in D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've been using D3 to write a small program to graph data in real time as it comes in from a device. The device returns data at a rate of 256 samples/second (approximately one sample per 3.9 ms), and it is important that I graph as many of the data points as possible.

Here is the function I have that redraws the line after each time interval which looks like it should do exactly what I want, but it doesn't. It graphs data too slowly:

```js
var ms_delay_between_samples = 3.9,
    current_i = 0,
    data = new Array(window_width_in_samples);

var path = svg.append("g")
           .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
           .append("path")
           .data([data])
           .attr("class", "line")
           .attr("d", line);

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) data[i] = null;

function tick() {

    data[current_i] = get_next_data_point();
    current_i = (current_i + 1) % window_width_in_samples;

    path
            .attr("d", line)
            .transition()
            .duration(ms_delay_between_samples)
            .ease("linear")
            .each("end", tick);

}
```

I have discovered that "graphing too slowly" comes from D3 itself. Basically, there is a ~17 ms delay that happens while waiting for the timer to kick in. Read the docs for [the duration function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-duration) and this text snippet from a different part of the docs to understand the problem I'm facing:

`Transitions start automatically upon creation after a delay which defaults to zero; however, note that a zero-delay transition actually starts after a minimal (~17ms) delay, pending the first timer callback.`

**The "slowness" I'm experiencing is from the ~17 ms duration *plus* the 3.9 ms duration I set. From all of the D3 examples I've seen, a duration is required for all transitions and redraws, but I need to redraw without a transition with duration. Does anybody know how I'd go about doing this?** I've spent a few hours searching online and came up with nothing.

I've even tried downsampling the data by 3 (to ~85.3 samples/second) and plotting 2 of the downsampled samples every 23.4 ms to get around the ~17 ms delay, but it just makes the delay time `23.4 ms + ~17 ms = ~40.4 ms` per sample instead of the `3.9 ms + ~17ms = ~20.9 ms` delay I was experiencing before.

Please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet for fast and smooth animation would be to forgo transitions and use `window.requestAnimationFrame`.  I think it would look something like this:

```
function tick() {

    data[current_i] = get_next_data_point();
    current_i = (current_i + 1) % window_width_in_samples;

    path.data(data).attr("d", line);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}
```

That would request data as quickly as the browser is able to receive and draw it.

Comment: I tried that and got these errors ``Error: Problem parsing d=""`` and ``Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'requestAnimationFrame'``. I've tried using ``window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(tick);`` (I'm using Chrome 23) and it got rid of the latter error but the former remains. Thoughts?

Comment: d3.timer (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_timer) makes use of requestAnimationFrame behind the scenes. You can use that function to update your scene as fast as possible; something like: d3.timer(draw).

Comment: See Jason Davies' comments: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/cKjsIPzuIoA/LrKHyghmHiwJ

Comment: Figured out my problem. I added some stuff and accidentally clobbered a local variable, plus ``path.data(data).attr("d", line);`` is actually supposed to be ``path.data([data]).attr("d", line);`` in my implementation. It's now rendering. Still not sufficiently fast enough, but I'll probably have to down-sample to get the kind of performance I want anyway. I'll update later with results. Also thanks for that @nautat, I'll look into that one too and decide which I like best!

Comment: You may actually be able to do without the `.data([data])` method in your `tick()`, as an array with an array referenced child element will update when that child is updated.  That may speed things up a little bit, since you won't have to keep clobbering your data with itself.

Comment: @nautat, thank you again. I was actually wondering how I'd be able to resume at the correct spot after a tab-switch, so that's perfect!

Comment: @Zikes, I'm a little confused with what you meant by "the array with an array reference child element". Can you explain more about what you mean by that and where it exists in my code? It seems you're implying it's already there...

Comment: @MikeHoller Previously in your code you set your `path` selection's data with `.data([data])`, which creates an array with the `data` array as a child.  This means that the array that you created and passed to the d3 selection has a child element which is externally referenced via the `data` variable, and subsequent changes to that variable will automatically transfer to the parent array.

Comment: Ah, of course! I'm fairly new to JavaScript and am not up on the terminology (I normally write Python/Java/PHP). I'm not used to hearing what I normally call "an array element" called a child, but it makes enough sense. That, and I'm lacking a bit of sleep now. Thanks for all your help, this is all starting to come together now!